# Unable to access @property on another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

A really noob question here.
I have 2 VCs.
One is called `SGPlayer` and another is `SGDownloader`. Basically I want to change the property of `SGDownloader` from the first class.
I import the `SGDownloader` class like this:

```
//  SGPlayer.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SGDownloader.h"

@interface SGPlayer : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) SGDownloader *downloaderClass;
```

`SGPlayer.m` is like this:

```
//  SGPlayer.m

#import "SGPlayer.h"

@interface SGPlayer ()

@end

@implementation SGPlayer
@synthesize downloaderClass;
```

I then set the downloadUrl property form the `SGDownloader` class in an action triggered by `UIButton` like that:

```
- (IBAction)loadURLButton:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadMyData" sender:nil];
    downloaderClass.downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
}
```

`NSLog` gives me (null) on my URL. If I use `prepareForSegue` method all is fine:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loadMyData"])
    {
        SGDownloader *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        vc.downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    }
}
```

The thing is *I don't want* to use `prepareForSegue` here.

I assume I might be misunderstanding the whole concept of how do you transfer the data between classes in Obj-C.

**Edit:**

I do have a *synthesised* property in the `SGDownloader` class:

```
@interface SGDownloader : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *downloadURL;

@end
```

Comment: And you don't want to use prepareForSegue because ... ? Anyway, you need some way to get a reference to that other controller. How are they related?

Comment: @Thilo because I want an abstract implementation of this method. The segue just might not be there next time so it's not an option for me. I don't think those controllers are at all related, these are just 2 custom classes.

Comment: I think you should attach your segue to a button (delete loadUrlButton method) and then use `prepareForSegue:` this is noraml. Do not invent bicycle!

Comment: @Stas I don't want this because I'm familiar with this approach. I want to try something different, independent of any segues at all.

Comment: So you want to invent a bicycle in some uncommon way and you ask us why it does not work? hmm...

Comment: @Stas It's not an uncommon way, I'm sure.

Comment: nevertheless, you have "A really noob question here"...

Comment: Did you try to put `downloaderClass.downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];` before `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadMyData" sender:nil];` in your buttonClick method?

Comment: @Stas tried that, not working

Comment: I would use prepareForSegue here. But anyway. Where exactly did yo assign a value to the property downloaderClass? 1st - are you sure that downloaderClass is not nil at that very moment when you try to assign its downloadURL property? If i is nil then obj-c will call the setter for a nil object and sending a message to a nil object seems to work and does not produce any error/exception at runtime. 2nd - how do you ensure that your property downloaderClass refers to the same instance as the segue destinationController? If you create an instance then storyboard will create one too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create property of downloadURL and synthesize it or you can use delegate to pass values between class

Comment: How does one use a delegate for this? As far as I've found out all delegates just have their own methods. Do I need to create methods for just changing one single @property?

Comment: you can create your own custom delegate for that.. use http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/             this link for help .. its the easiest and guarented way to transfer values between classes..

Answer (score 3):

Hi make property of `downloadURL`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSUrl * downloadURL;
```

Comment: I have it in my SGDownloader class already. And I also made another property on SGPlayer just to be sure.

Comment: so you are not getting value in NSUrl?

Comment: Yeah, the value is nil only when I don't use the prepareForSegue method. With it, all is fine.

Comment: SGDownloader * downloaderClass = [[SGDownloader alloc]initWithNibName:@"SGDownloader" bundle:nil];
    downloaderClass.downloadURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

Comment: had you @synthesize downloadURL;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21378/discussion-between-rajneesh071-and-sergiusgee)

Comment: hey i searched and found that in storyboard , you can make object of class using UIStoryboardSegue... in storyBoard using this you can make class object then able to send data.. :)

Comment: I ended up using a delegate, a simple and powerful decision.

Comment: its too simple method i suggest you..and solution is according to your question.anyways as your wish..

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above your `downloaderClass` is nil when you try and set the property. So before you set it you can use `self.downloaderClass = [[SGDownloader alloc] init....]`.

You then have to make sure when you switch view controllers that you are using this instance and not one instantiated by the storyboard (cant help here as i havent used storyboards).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your `downloaderClass` property is `nil`, not just it's `downloadURL`. That is why you get null. In the `prepareForSegue` it is instantiated for you from the storyboard, I recommend you use it there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I just don't want to use it there, unfortunately.

Comment: @SergiusGee, if you just don't want to do it right then feel free to do it wrong. But please do not blame those who provide you with the best advice available.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately yo do not show the full code. I guess that if your `self.downloaderClass` is not nil, as suggested before, then it is a different instance of oyur view controller than `segue.destinationViewController`. You may have created an instance but that does not stop storyboard from creating its own.

I'd rather suggest to use `prepareForSegue` when using storyboard. Simply because this method is designed for exactly this purpose.

BTW, `downloaderClass` is not the smartest name for that object, because it does not refer to a class (that would be a property of type Class*) but to an acutal instance. `downloadViewController` or so would be more appropriate in terms of "speaking code". However, this does not cause your problem.

And, of course, downloadURL must be accessible from outside that class. That needs to be a property too. On the other hand it seems to be derrived from a constant string value. If that is true and remains true while your project carries on, then there is no point in setting the value from outside. You could as well set it in an appropriate init method within the class.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide memory to your `SGDownloader *downloaderClass` before you assign a property.
Use *alloc* before you use that `downloaderClass`.

Comment: don't know why people vote this down. This is a common mistake. Just like you calling obj.array without doing obj.array = [[NSArray alloc]init]; or making obj.array pointing to something.

Comment: while this answer maybe points into the right direction, it is so incomplete that it should be considered wrong.

Comment: I dont see anything missing, besides somebody else gave the same answer much later than I did and he's been upvoted.

Comment: This answer may lead to the solution. downloaderClass is probably nil. But just creating an instance and assign that reference to downloaderClass would not solve the issue at all. It has to be the identical instance of the view controller that storyboard would present. alloc/init does not fix this issue.